# Media with aspx extension is not working

Tags: media-library, urls, mediaurls

We have migrated to Sitecore 10.1 from Sitecore 8.7.

In Sitecore 8, For-example, if the image location is /-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo

Then the following url returns the same image

```
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo.ashx
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo.jpg
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo.aspx.
```

I noticed that media item with **.aspx** is showing 404 error (The resource cannot be found) in Sitecore 10. Other extensions like ashx,jpg,png shows the correct media item.

The following url shows the correct image in Sitecore 10

```
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo.ashx
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo.jpg
```

The **aspx** link doesn't work and shows 404 error.

```
<site-url>/-/media/Project/Os-Theme/Styles/images/logo.aspx.
```

Is there any setting to use **aspx** in the media item in Sitecore 10?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sitecore 10` doesn't support this. We had one `asp.net` application and one `HTML site` hosted as an Application within the Sitecore site. And in `9.1` these two applications were working fine with `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` settings. But after `Sitecore 10` upgrade we found HTML application is working fine (we need to change the application to a Virtual directory) but `asp.net` application stops working. We had a discussion with Sitecore support also but no luck.
So if you have a media extension with `aspx`, it is possible that Sitecore will not support that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

`aspx` extension is reserved for a particular type of files on IIS - they are handled with `w3wp` process:

- first translated into c# code,
- then `csc.exe` builds C# sourcode,
- and eventually `Page.OnLoad` is being executed.

If it was allowed to return the content of an aspx file, that would be a huge security risk.

You can read more about `aspx` files handling e.g. here:

https://blog.viettelcybersecurity.com/deep-understand-aspx-file-handling-and-some-related-attack-vector/

You can try using `Media.RequestExtension` setting:

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="aspx" />
```

but that's not recommended for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mark. But it used to work for Sitecore 8.7. Is there a way to do it via custom code using a pipeline?

Comment: You can try using `<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="aspx" />` but that's not recommended for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />` in that case it will work for all extensions, but as said above that's not recommended for sure, especially for .aspx extension